# about google Admob ads?

Tags: android, admob, ads, banner, interstitial

Everyone I hope everythings going ok. I have problem with Admob when I chose banner or interstials and I paste the unit  Id on my  android appliaction doesn't showing up so if anyone here can help me and thanks advanced. (**I try it with other apps but The same problem**) .

Comment: please add your code and logs ( filter for Ads )

Comment: Did you edit your refill rate?

Comment: @Michal_196 no Im just edit file strings.xml

Comment: @AmodGokhale ok